# Amazon S3 Getting 501 Error on PUT

Tags: iphone, ios, amazon-s3

In testing a new app one tester always has his uploads to S3 fail.  We're sending a PUT request of a ~1.2mb file to S3 and setting it's ACL perms.  For him, he always gets a 501 - Not Implemented error.

Here are his headers on the request:

```
"Accept-Encoding" = gzip; 
Authorization = "AWS ###:###";
"Content-Encoding" = gzip;
"Content-Length" = 1420267;
"Content-Type" = "application/octet-stream";
Date = "Thu, 6 Oct 2011 02:59:47 +0000";
"User-Agent" = "MyApp 1.0 (iPhone; iPhone OS 4.3.1; en_US)";
"x-amz-acl" = "public-read-write";
```

Here are the response headers:

```
Connection = close;
"Content-Length" = 321;
"Content-Type" = "application/xml";
Date = "Thu, 06 Oct 2011 03:00:14 GMT";
Server = AmazonS3;
```

Any thoughts are welcome!

Response comes back with status code 501 and string - "A header you provided implies functionality that is not 
implemented"

Comment: Is there a response? What is it?

Comment: Edited post to include response status code and string

Comment: I hope your question gets answered.  The same thing is happening to me.  https://github.com/LearnBoost/knox/issues/43

Answer (score 9):

501 response code from Amazon may be sent if no Content-Length is supplied.

Since you are saying that you do, I suggest running the request through a proxy ( [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) for Mac or [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) for Windows) and making sure that the request that's being sent actually includes the Content-Length header

Comment: I know this was like, almost 10 years ago, but thanks for commenting this. I'm very new to S3, and that's what my company's CRM uses for hosting, and the API docs for that CRM don't specify including Content-Length, and seeing this finally got it working.

Answer (score 8):

The response body contains XML that lists the header it's not happy with, like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error>
<Code>NotImplemented</Code>
<Message>A header you provided implies functionality that is not implemented</Message>
<Header>If-Modified-Since</Header>
</Error>
```

I set the cache policy on my NSURLRequest to NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData and it stopped adding the unwanted If-Modified-Since header:

```
    mutableURLRequest = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:theURL];
    [mutableURLRequest setCachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData];
```

Answer (score 4):

as @Alon Burg has pointed out that S3 expects the `Content-Length` header to be set. You cant directly use streams (or I didnt figure out how); `Fetch` (or node-fetch) when passing in a `ReadStream` as the body, it sets the `transport-encoding` header to `chunked` which S3 does not support (when using `putObject`).

The fix is to first convert the `ReadStream` to a `Buffer` (or string) and pass that as a body which allows `fetch` to calculate the `Content-Length` behind the door

Answer (score 3):

Some update on this topic, as I was searching for answers myself. This seems to be a rather general error message, with more than one possible reason.

For javascript api, there was a bug fix for empty body on 24 Dec 2012:

- **RestXMLClient include Content-Length header for empty bodies** https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues/15

Recently on IOS 8, there are problems with aggressive (and non-standard) caching, which Amazon does not like. If there was any GetObject before, If-Modified-Since header is sent for subsequent requests for same object/url, even for PUT requests:

- **aws-sdk-ios**: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ios/issues/40 **AWSS3PutObjectRequest Failed on iOS8 Beta 5 with Not Implemented error.**
- **aws-sdk-js**: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues/376 **PutObject on IOS 8**

Comment: As @Alon Burg mentioned, AWS is trying and failing to tell you that you're missing the `Content-Length`

Comment: I only found about "content-length" when Googling for error - as I see, Javascript API takes care of length.
I was interested in "PutObject on IOS 8" (aws-sdk-js) issue, where I see no mention that content-length is the problem, but caching.
I was probably unclear with this post.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem in Perl with CPAN's Net::Amazon::S3::Client. I examined the request and response and I pieced together the problem, which was that I lacked the ability to request via HTTPS. I fixed it by installing LWP::Protocol::https.

Answer (score 0):

I too faced this problem , while implementing putObject in node js code , and found that i didn't stringfy the JSON body , which resulted in the same error.